# to show $ϵ> 0$ & for each polynomial $p$, $\sup \{|p(z) − z^{−1}| : z \in A\} ≥ϵ$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $0 < r < R$ and $A = \{z : r ≤ |z| ≤R\}$. Show that there is a positive number $\epsilon> 0$ such that for each polynomial $p$, $\sup \{|p(z) − z^{−1}| : z \in A\} \ge\epsilon$

---

I have no idea at all how to solve this problem.can anyone help me please.

Comment: Putting {curly braces} and "sup" _outside_ the math tags is not good usage.  Please see my recent edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

Suppose that for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ there exists a polynomial $\,p_n(z)\,$ s.t.

$$\sup_{z\in A}\,\,\left|p_n(z)-\frac{1}{z}\right|<\frac{1}{n}$$

What can you say about $\,\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(z)\;,\;\;z\in A}\,$ ?

Comment: the polynomial must have maximum value at $|z|=R$. but in this case it get its maximum value at $z=0$. a contradiction.-am I right now?